# AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: python, django, attributeerror, django-middleware

I'm running my Django code, but get this error

```
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'
```

My Django version is 1.8.2, and here is my middleware class of setting.py

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (

'khxia.middlewares.PeeweeConnectionMiddleware',

'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'subdomains.middleware.SubdomainURLRoutingMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',

'referral.middlewares.ReferralRecordMiddleware',
'common.middlewares.ExceptionMiddleware',
)
```

Here is my full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/Users/motion/kuaixiao_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 189, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/Users/motion/kuaixiao_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 218, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/Users/motion/kuaixiao_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 268, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return callback(request, **param_dict)
  File "/Users/motion/Documents/GitHub/khx2/khxia/home/views.py", line 68, in server_error
    res = render(request, 'home/500.html')
  File "/Users/motion/Documents/GitHub/khx2/khxia/common/shortcuts.py", line 40, in render
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'
```

The line 68 of views.py is:

```
def server_error(request):
    res = render(request, 'home/500.html')
    res.status_code = 500
    return res
```

The render function is shown blow:

```
def render(request, template_name, dictionary=None):
    """

    :param request: Django request object
    :param template_name: template name
    :param dictionary: parameter of dictionary
    """
    dictionary = dictionary or {}
    dictionary.update({
        'settings': settings,
        'DEBUG': settings.DEBUG,
        'server_time': int(time.time()),
    })

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        dictionary['user_hashid'] = hashid.encode(request.user.id)

    temp = template_name.replace('.html', '').split('/')
    if len(temp) == 1:
        module = 'v{name}'.format(name=temp[0].capitalize())
    else:
        name = ''.join([t.capitalize() for t in temp])
        module = 'v{name}'.format(name=name)
    dictionary['load_module'] = module
    return django_render(
        request,
        template_name,
        dictionary
    )
```

Comment: post your full stacktrace

Comment: i guess the problem is from shortcuts.py you need to show it.

Comment: ok，i gonna show it. thanks man

Comment: you got your ans @at14 has said the correct thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the order in which you have put your middleware.

request.user is added to the WSGI Request object by the AuthenticationMiddleware.

place

```
'khxia.middlewares.PeeweeConnectionMiddleware',
```

this middleware after AuthenticationMiddleware, or as the last middleware

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IntelliJ and invalidated your caches or deleted .iml file, `right-click` on your project folder and select `Open Module Settings`. In the window that opens, select `Facets` under `Project Settings`, click `+` and select `Django`. Update the `Django project root` and `Settings` locations; if done correctly, `manage.py` and `migrations` will be located automatically. Be sure to also check `Project` settings for correct `Python SDK`, and `Modules->Dependencies` for matching `Module SDK`.